# 3rd Person Camera Clipping Walls in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity I am creating a 3rd person game with the camera following the player, while also being able to rotate on its own. Right now when I rotate the camera and there's a wall, the camera seems to go through the wall.

I have tried adding a sphere collider and a rigidbody to the camera, but that did not help. I also created an empty GameObject with a sphere collider as the parent and making the camera a child. I also tried creating an empty child with a sphere collider.

I have attached a video of the situation along with my code for  the camera script. The shadow in the photo is actually the wall that my camera is going through.

[Video of wall clipping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF1VI.jpg) Any suggestions of how to fix this ?

```csharp
public class OrbitCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform target;
    public float rotSpeed = 1.5f;
    private float vertRotY;
    private float horiRotX;
    private Vector3 offSet;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        vertRotY = transform.eulerAngles.y;
        offSet = target.position - transform.position;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.forward, out hit, 100f))
        {

        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Wall")
        {
            print("touching wall");
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        float horiInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        if (horiInput != 0)
        {
            vertRotY += horiInput * rotSpeed;
            
        }
        else
        {
            vertRotY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotSpeed * 3;

        }

        if (vertInput == 0)
        {
            horiRotX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotSpeed * 3;
            horiRotX = Mathf.Clamp(horiRotX, -45f, 20f);
        }

        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(-horiRotX, vertRotY, 0);
        transform.position = target.position - (rotation * offSet);
        
        //transform.Rotate(rotation.eulerAngles);
        transform.LookAt(target);
        //transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position, Vector3.up, vertRotY);
        //transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position, Vector3.left, rotSpeed * 3);
    }
}
```

Here is my player movement script:

```csharp
public class RelativeMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private Transform target;
    
    public float moveSpeed = 6.0f;
    public float rotSpeed = 15.0f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 15.0f;
    public float gravity = -9.8f;
    public float terminalVelocity = -20.0f;
    public float minFall = -1.5f;

    private float _vertSpeed;
    private ControllerColliderHit _contact;

    private CharacterController _charController;
    private Animator _animator;

    
    //Physics force
    public float pushForce = 3.0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {
        _vertSpeed = minFall;

        _charController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {

        // start with zero and add movement components progressively
        Vector3 movement = Vector3.zero;

        // x z movement transformed relative to target
        float horInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vertInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        if (horInput != 0 || vertInput != 0) {
            movement.x = horInput * moveSpeed;
            movement.z = vertInput * moveSpeed;
            movement = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(movement, moveSpeed);

            Quaternion tmp = target.rotation;
            target.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, target.eulerAngles.y, 0);
            movement = target.TransformDirection(movement);
            target.rotation = tmp;

            // face movement direction
            //transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(movement);
            Quaternion direction = Quaternion.LookRotation(movement);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, direction, rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            _animator.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        }
        else
        {
            _animator.SetBool("isRunning", false);
        }
        //_animator.SetFloat("Speed", movement.sqrMagnitude);

        // raycast down to address steep slopes and dropoff edge
        bool hitGround = false;
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (_vertSpeed < 0 && Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit)) {
            float check = (_charController.height + _charController.radius) / 1.9f;
            hitGround = hit.distance <= check;  // to be sure check slightly beyond bottom of capsule
        }

        // y movement: possibly jump impulse up, always accel down
        // could _charController.isGrounded instead, but then cannot workaround dropoff edge
        if (hitGround) {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) {
                _vertSpeed = jumpSpeed;
            } else {
                _vertSpeed = minFall;
                _animator.SetBool("isJumping", false);
            }
        } else {
            _vertSpeed += gravity * 5 * Time.deltaTime;
            if (_vertSpeed < terminalVelocity) {
                _vertSpeed = terminalVelocity;
            }
            if (_contact != null ) {    // not right at level start
                _animator.SetBool("isJumping", true);
            }

            // workaround for standing on dropoff edge
            if (_charController.isGrounded) {
                if (Vector3.Dot(movement, _contact.normal) < 0) {
                    movement = _contact.normal * moveSpeed;
                } else {
                    movement += _contact.normal * moveSpeed;
                }
            }
        }
        movement.y = _vertSpeed;

        movement *= Time.deltaTime;
        _charController.Move(movement);
    }
   
    // store collision to use in Update
    void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit) {
        _contact = hit;

         //Physics method portion

        Rigidbody body = hit.collider.attachedRigidbody;
        if (body != null && !body.isKinematic){
            body.velocity = hit.moveDirection * pushForce;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to make a new empty game object with a collider and make it a child of the camera with the same position.

Comment: Hey. That didn't quite work, anymore suggestions? I also tried creating an empty GameObject with a sphere collider as the parent and making the camera a child. Neither ways worked. Thanks.

Comment: what is your wall collider is it mesh collider?

Comment: Yes, there is a mesh collider on the walls. The walls are just scaled cubes.

Comment: @Dani K then try to replace the collider of the wall with box collider because continous collision detection is not supporeted with mesh collider with rigidbody.

Comment: I changed it so that all the walls have a box collider, but even with a sphere collider on the camera it does not work. Anything other methods? Thank you for all the help so far btw.

Comment: @Dani K both collider must have collider.isTrigger disabled to work.

Comment: Yup. Neither the camera nor the wall is a trigger.

Comment: @Dani K add rigidbody and disable rigidbody.useGravity on it.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this as well.  I wanted the camera to follow the player but also "rotate around", so that when I looked up and down, the camera continued to look at the player.  Clipping of course ensued.

I solved this by not trying to change the localPosition of the camera, or collision checking.  Using the camera object's RotateAround method will change the localPosition values of the camera object, making it difficult to properly position the camera when collisions occur.

Instead, simply place an empty game object at the desired height of your camera in the player as a child object.  I called it CameraPivot.  then make the camera a child of the CameraPivot object and position it as desired.

Now the trick here is to leave the camera position alone except for the z Axis.  If you change the cameraPivot object's localRotation, the camera will naturally follow that object, and the localPosition values of the camera do not change.  Then, use a Raycast from the camera pivot to the camera to detect if there are walls, ground, objects etc.  if you hit an object, use the hitinfo's distance property for your z axis.

Sample Script is below, which includes comments.  This was tested in one of my sample games.  Now the script also allows for first person and third person view.  Note that some clipping on the walls, floor and roof may occur, so you want to check the camera's fov and near clipping plane. I've also used an offset.  these can be adjusted to get the desired results.  Note also I use a lookat method to look at the camera pivot, but there is no reason you cannot change the camera's rotation at any time as desired.

```
using UnityEngine;

#region Description
// This class manages Player and camera rotation
// It rotates the player object on the Y axis based on mouse x input;

// If in third person view, it also rotates the camera around the player object on the X axis based on mouse y input
// and moves the camera back and forth along the Z axis if it collides with an object.
// You get behavior similar to a camera.main.transform.RotateAround() methodology,
// but with the added benefit of collision detection and easy control over the camera's max distance

// In first person view, it rotates the camera on the X axis based on mouse y input

// This class is attached to the camera object
// transform.parent.parent is the player object
// transform.parent is the camera's parent object (cameraPivot)

#endregion Description
public class CameraClipViewer : MonoBehaviour
{
  private bool isFirstPerson;
  private Vector3 firstPersonView;
  private Vector3 thirdPersonView;

  private float mouseX; // the mouse x-axis input
  private float mouseY; // the mouse y-axis input
  private float rotationX = 0f; // the current x-axis rotation of the camera, frame by frame
  private float rotationY = 0f; // the current y-axis rotation of the Player, frame by frame

  [SerializeField]
  private LayerMask mask; // the layers the camera should collide with
  [SerializeField]
  private float sensitivity = 5f; // the sensitivity of the mouse x and y-axis rotation
  [SerializeField]
  private float maxXRotation = 90f; // the maximum x-axis rotation of the camera
  [SerializeField]
  private float maxDistance; // the maximum distance the camera can be from an object before it is moved back
  [SerializeField]
  private float zOffset = 0.35f; // distance to maintain between the camera and collider to avoid clipping
  [SerializeField]
  private float nearClippingPlane = 0.01f; // min camera clipping plane to avoid clipping


  private void Start()
  {
    isFirstPerson = false;
    firstPersonView = new Vector3(0, 0, 0.3f);
    thirdPersonView = new Vector3(0, 0, -4f);
    transform.localPosition = isFirstPerson ? firstPersonView : thirdPersonView;

    // make sure the max distance is positive
    maxDistance = Vector3.Distance(transform.parent.position, transform.localPosition);

    // make sure the near clipping plane is positive and set it to avoid clipping sideways along a wall.
    if (nearClippingPlane < 0) nearClippingPlane = 0;
    transform.GetComponent<Camera>().nearClipPlane = nearClippingPlane;
  }

  private void Update()
  {
    mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
    SwitchCameraView();
    RotateCameraView();
  }

  private void SwitchCameraView()
  {
    if (!Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C)) return;
    isFirstPerson = !isFirstPerson;
    transform.localPosition = isFirstPerson ? firstPersonView : thirdPersonView;
  }

  private void RotateCameraView()
  {
    // Update current rotation values
    rotationX -= mouseY * sensitivity;
    rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(rotationX, -maxXRotation, maxXRotation);
    rotationY += mouseX * sensitivity;

    // Rotate the player object based on mouse x input
    transform.parent.parent.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, rotationY, 0f);

    // Perform rotations based on current camera view settings
    if (isFirstPerson)
      transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationX, 0f, 0f); // rotate the camera based on mouse y input
    else
    {
      // rotate the camera parent object based on mouse y input
      transform.parent.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationX, 0f, 0f);

      // Get the normalized direction from camera to parent object
      Vector3 direction = (transform.position - transform.parent.position).normalized;

      // Position the camera based on if the camera is colliding with an object
      Ray ray = new Ray(transform.parent.position, direction);
      transform.localPosition = Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit, maxDistance + zOffset, mask)
        ? new Vector3(0, 0, -(hit.distance - zOffset))
        : new Vector3(0, 0, -maxDistance);

      // Finally, make the camera look at the parent object
      transform.LookAt(transform.parent);

    }
  }
}
```